# Print without space in python 3

Tags: python, printing

I'm new to Python, and I'm wondering how to print multiple values without having the extra space added in between. I want the output `ab` rather than `a b` without having to call `print` twice:

```
print("a", end="")
print("b")
```

Also, I have the following code:

```
a = 42
b = 84
```

and I want to print their values as `a = 42, b = 84`, yet if I do

```
print("a = ", a, ", ", b = ", b)
```

extra spaces are added (it outputs `a =  42 , b =  84`)

Whereas the Java style,

```
print("a = " + a + ", b = " + b)
```

raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print without a newline or space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `sep` parameter to get rid of the spaces:

```
>>> print("a","b","c")
a b c
>>> print("a","b","c",sep="")
abc
```

I don't know what you mean by "Java style"; in Python you can't add strings to (say) integers that way, although if `a` and `b` are strings it'll work.  You have several other options, of course:

```
>>> print("a = ", a, ", b = ", b, sep="") 
a = 2, b = 3
>>> print("a = " + str(a) + ", b = " + str(b))
a = 2, b = 3
>>> print("a = {}, b = {}".format(a,b))
a = 2, b = 3
>>> print(f"a = {a}, b = {b}")
a = 2, b = 3
```

The last one requires Python 3.6 or later. For earlier versions, you can simulate the same effect (although I don't recommend this in general, it comes in handy sometimes and there's no point pretending otherwise):

```
>>> print("a = {a}, b = {b}".format(**locals()))
a = 2, b = 3
>>> print("b = {b}, a = {a}".format(**locals()))
b = 3, a = 2
```

Answer (score 6):

The actual syntax of the print() function is

```
print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

You can see it has an arg `sep` with default value `' '`. That's why space gets inserted in between.

```
print("United","States")            #Output: United States
print("United","States",sep="")     #Output: UnitedStates
```

Comment: the separator set to nothing helped me erase whitespace in front of output resulting from \n\n

Answer (score 1):

To separate the strings or values you can use sep parameter in print()

```
print(a,b,sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
print("%d%d" %(a,b))
```

to print a and b not seperated by spaces in form of a formatted string. This is similar to the one in c.

Answer (score 0):

`print()` will automatically make spaces between arguments.

```
>>> print("a", "b", "c")
a b c
```

To have more control over spacing, you could use string formatting:

```
>>> v0, v1, v2 = "a", "b", "c"
>>> print("%s%s%s" % (v0, v1, v2))
abc
>>> print("%s%s%s".format(v0, v1, v2)
abc
>>> print(f"{v0}{v1}{v2}")
abc
```

I like this guide on the subject: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score -2):

On [this page](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html) the answer is to print your normal text and at the end to use 
`sep=""`.

So the command

```
print("Hole", hole, "Par", par, sep="")
```

will give

```
"Hole1Par4"
```

assuming that `hole==1` and `par==4`.