# How do I print my line of text with no spaces

Tags: python

I am trying to get two values from the user and print a line of text with the user input.

```
char1 = input("Please enter the first character: ")
char2 = input("Please enter the secound character: ")

width = int(input("Please enter the width of the innermost triangle: "))

if width % 2 == 0:
    print ("ERROR - number is even")
    quit()

print ("")
print (char1*11,char2*1,char1*11)
```

This is my current output:

```
YYYYYYYYYYY + YYYYYYYYYYY
```

I am trying to print it with no spaces so that it looks like this:

```
YYYYYYYYYYY+YYYYYYYYYYY
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print without space in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700558/print-without-space-in-python-3)

Answer (score 1):

Print your output like this:

```
print ("{}{}{}".format(char1*11,char2*1,char1*11))
```

or you can use sep if you are using Python 3:

```
print (char1*11,char2*1,char1*11, sep="")
```

Read some more about printing here:

http://www.python-course.eu/python3_print.php