# Concatenating strings in python without spaces

Tags: python, string, concatenation

How can I print my strings so that there are no spaces between each output.

```
name_input = str(input("Please enter your name"))
name_input = name_input.strip()
name_input = name_input.lower()
first_letter = name_input[0]
first_space = name_input.find(" ")
last_name = name_input[first_space:]
last_name_3 = last_name[0:4]
random_number = random.randrange(0,999)
print("*********************************************")
print("Username Generator")
print("*********************************************")
print(first_letter + last_name_3, random_number)`
```

Incorrect output: b fir 723

what I require: bfir723

Comment: [Print without space in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700558/print-without-space-in-python-3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `strip()` function for this:

```
print(first_letter.strip() + last_name_3.strip() + str(random_number).strip())
```

Comment: That did remove the space between the strings however the strip function did not remove the spaces between the numbers. Current output bfir 723

Comment: @BaileyFY: I've edited my answer to trim numbers as well.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: print(first_letter.strip() + last_name_3.strip(), (random_number).strip())
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strip'
Error message

Comment: You've missed out `str` in `str(random_number).strip()` part.

Answer (score 11):

use the separator parameter to the print function, to remove the space by passing in an argument with no space.

Like this:

```
print(first_letter, last_name_3, random_number, sep='')
```

The default separator is a space. Specification is here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `strip()` and `sep=''`

You only need one or the other, but `sep=''` is cleaner and more beautiful

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do

```
print(first_letter + last_name + str(random_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out a combination of .strip() and ,sep='' was required to print correctly:

```
print(first_letter.strip() + last_name_3.strip(), random_number, sep="")
```