# spacing for triangle pattern in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

The following code prints a pattern but I have problem with spacing. I want to print it in a triangle fashion

```
def triangle(n): 
    s = ""
    for i in range(0,n):
        s +=  "{}".format((i+1)%10)
        j=s*1
        print( s,'*1=',j)


triangle(9)
```

This is the output I get

```
1 *1= 1
12 *1= 12
123 *1= 123
1234 *1= 1234
12345 *1= 12345
123456 *1= 123456
1234567 *1= 1234567
12345678 *1= 12345678
123456789 *1= 123456789
```

Comment: Please include the expected output

Comment: I suggest that you search for python's string formatting...

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print without space in python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700558/print-without-space-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3):

If you meen this

```
         1 * 1 = 1
        12 * 1 = 12
       123 * 1 = 123
      1234 * 1 = 1234
     12345 * 1 = 12345
    123456 * 1 = 123456
   1234567 * 1 = 1234567
  12345678 * 1 = 12345678
 123456789 * 1 = 123456789
```

then you need ie. `{:9s}` (for `string`) to add extra spaces (or `{:9d}` for `int`)

```
def triangle(n): 
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        a = 10*a + i
        print('{:9d} * {} = {}'.format(a, b, a*b))

triangle(9)
```

See: [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

---

**EDIT:** to use `n` instead of `9` you need `{:{}d}` and `.format(a, n, ...)`

```
    print('{:{}d} * {} = {}'.format(a, n, b, a*b))
```

---

**EDIT:** version with two arguments

```
def triangle(n, b): 
    a = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        a = 10*a + i
        print('{:{}d} * {} = {}'.format(a, n, b, a*b))

triangle(5, 3)

    1 * 3 = 3
   12 * 3 = 36
  123 * 3 = 369
 1234 * 3 = 3702
12345 * 3 = 37035
```

---

**EDIT:** some explanations:

**Line** `a = 10*a + i`:

You used string and concatenation to create string `"1234"` from string `"123"` - `"1234" = "123" + "4"`. I use integer and `*10` to create integer `1234` from integer `123` - `1234 = 123*10 + 4`. (and now I can use integer `1234` to calcutate `1234*b` in next line)

**Line** `print('{:{}d} * {} = {}'.format(a, n, b, a*b))`

To make more readable you can use

- numbers (because arguments in `format()` are numbered - 0,1,2,...)

  ```
  print('{0:{1}d} * {2} = {3}'.format(a, n, b, a*b))
  ```

  or even (`d` means `decimal` or `int`)

  ```
  print('{0:{1:d}d} * {2:d} = {3:d}'.format(a, n, b, a*b))
  ```
- names

  ```
  print('{x:{y}d} * {z} = {v}'.format(x=a, y=n, z=b, v=a*b))
  ```

  or even

  ```
  print('{x:{y:d}d} * {z:d} = {v:d}'.format(x=a, y=n, z=b, v=a*b))
  ```

`{:9}` (or `{x:9d}`) will get integer value and create 9 char length text aligned to right so you get extra spaces on left side.

Try `{:<9}` to get 9 char length text aligned to left

```
1         * 3 = 3
12        * 3 = 36
123       * 3 = 369
1234      * 3 = 3702
12345     * 3 = 37035
123456    * 3 = 370368
1234567   * 3 = 3703701
12345678  * 3 = 37037034
123456789 * 3 = 370370367
```

or `{:^9}` to get centered text

```
    1     * 3 = 3
   12     * 3 = 36
   123    * 3 = 369
  1234    * 3 = 3702
  12345   * 3 = 37035
 123456   * 3 = 370368
 1234567  * 3 = 3703701
12345678  * 3 = 37037034
123456789 * 3 = 370370367
```

See more: [pyformat.info](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: see example in answer. You use `{:{}d}` and `format(a, n, ...)`

Comment: can you please explain the last two lines of the code

Comment: see explanation in answer