# Python 3.6 - Any input given will give it an extra space after the input

Tags: python

I'm still only learning the basics of Python, but my code is this:

```
name = input("Hi, what is your name? ")
print("Hi,", str(name), ". We need to check your funds for all your drinking,", name, ".")
```

When I run it, I type in 'Bojack' (without the quote marks) but it'll always come back with:

```
Hi, Bojack . We need to check your funds for all your drinking, Bojack .
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700558/print-without-space-in-python-3

Comment: @Rawing... please answer more questions... we need you on the dupe hammer team.

Answer (score 2):

You can print strings like this:

```
print("My name is {name}.".format(name=name))
```

Comment: Or even `print(f'My name is {name}.')`, since it's 3.6

Comment: Sorry im so py2.7, that's super neat - will start doing more of this.

Comment: Worked great, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't (as you seem to think) that `name` is being assigned `'Bojak '` (with a space) - the problem is that when you `print()` like that python3 separates the arguements by default with a space.

you can override that by passing the `sep` arguement:

```
print("Hi,", str(name), ". We need to check your funds for all your drinking,", name, ".", sep="")
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is occurring is that you are joining the strings with a comma (`,`). A way to avoid this from happening is to use string concatenation:

```
name = input("Hi, what is your name? ")
print("Hi, " + name + ". We need to check your funds for all your drinking, " + name + ".")
```

Output:

```
Hi, Bojack. We need to check your funds for all your drinking, Bojack.
```

While this solution is not the most efficient and clean, it is easy to understand for Python beginners. For faster solutions, string formatting is better.

Hope this helped!

Comment: String concatenation is a bad practice: it's less efficient and not as clean as formatting

Comment: Using this now, thank you, appreciate it.