# Why do i keep getting bin/sh: 1 : : not found

Tags: python, linux

I'm learning python programming and wanted to try out some scripts in changing MAC Addresses in linux but i keep getting the following error:

```
/bin/sh : 1 : ifconfigeth0down : not found
/bin/sh : 1 : ifconfigeth0hw : not found
/bin/sh : 1 : ifconfigeth0up : not found
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me out on this, thank you.

The code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import_subprocess

interface = input("interface >")

new_mac = input("new MAC >")

subprocess.call("ifconfig" + interface + "down", shell=True)

subprocess.call("ifconfig + interface + "hw ether" + new_mac, shell=True)

subprocess.call("ifconfig" + interface + "up", shell=True)*
```

Comment: Put a space after "ifconfig" making it "ifconfig ". Same for "down" but this time, put the space before.

Comment: Put the command in a variable and print it before you run it. That will make it easier to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: It would be better to use a list instead of a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print without space in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12700558/608639). Also see [How to step through Python code to help debug issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4929251/608639)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't have spaces around the arguments to the command.

But it would be better to avoid shell parsing entirely, by passing a list instead of a string.

```
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
supprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])
```